# VB.NET Listbox selectedindex

Tags: vb.net, listbox

In my code i select excel files to add them to a listbox, I then run some code that will replace a certain cell on all excel files in the list. Everytime it changes a cell in the excel file it will go to the next one in the listbox using

```
Me.ListBox2.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox2.SelectedIndex + 1
```

But when it reaches the end of the list it gives me an error. How can i let my listbox know that it reached the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a check like this:

```
if Me.ListBox2.SelectedIndex + 1  < Me.ListBox2.items.count then
    Me.ListBox2.SelectedIndex + = 1
End if
```

Comment: Don't seem to work, it doesn't select the next item, but stays at the first one.

Comment: Use  +=1 to short it down a bit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do a For/Each/Next to loop through the items like this:

```
For Each ListItem As Object In ListBox2.Items

    'Set Active item as selected
    ListBox2.SelectedItem = ListItem

    'manipulate file
    UpdateExcelFile(ListItem.ToString)

Next
```

Comment: Looks indeed like a cleaner aproach, will look into this.

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun. You can do this without using IF/END IF
Following code will move the selectedindex to the next item until it reaches the end of the listbox.

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex += Math.Abs(CInt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1))
```

Comment: I would not recommend using this approach. Just posting it to show alternate ways to do it. ;)

Comment: Oh, someone doesn't like unreadable oneliner-code. ;) Oh well.